# How to use function defined in a groovy script using the "evaluate" method from Java

Tags: java, groovy

I just discover Groovy call from Java and have problem with this case :

I have a groovy file : "`test.groovy`"

```
a = 1.0
def mul2( x ) { 2.0 * x }
```

And I want to use it from Java code like this

```
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell();
gs.parse( new File( ".../test.groovy" ) ).run();

System.out.printf( "a = %s%n", gs.evaluate("a") ); // ok
System.out.printf( "mul2(a) = %s%n", gs.evaluate( "mul2(a)" ) ); // error
```

The error is :

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.mul2() is applicable for argument types: (BigDecimal) values: [1.0]
```

What I have to do to have access to function defined in groovy script, using evaluate() method ?

I need to use "evaluate" method because I want finally to evaluate something like `Math.sin( a * mul2(Math.Pi) )`.

---

Now I have 4 solutions (the forth is what I searched for) :

1. use closure as in answer of 'Szymon Stepniak'
2. use import static as in answer of 'daggett'
3. extends the script that contains Java functions with the script that evaluate the expression :

...the class (in Java, not Groovy)...

```
  public static abstract class ScriptClass extends Script
  {
    double mul2( double x )
    {
      return x * 2;
    }
  }
```

...the code...

```
  CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
  config.setScriptBaseClass(ScriptClass.class.getName());

  GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(config);

  System.out.printf( "result = %s%n", gs.evaluate("mul2(5.05)") );
```

That works but the code is in Java, not what I want, but I note it here for ones need to do that

4. And finally extends groovy script :

the groovy file :

```
double mul2( x ) { x * 2 } 
a=mul2(3.33)
```

the java code that use it

```
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
Class<?> r = gcl.parseClass( resourceToFile("/testx.groovy") );
CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
config.setScriptBaseClass(r.getName());
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(gcl, config);    

System.out.printf( "mul2(5.05) = %s%n", gs.evaluate("mul2(5.05)") );

// WARNING : call super.run() in evaluate expression to have access to variables defined in script
System.out.printf( "result = %s%n", gs.evaluate("super.run(); mul2(a) / 123.0") );
```

It's exactly what I wanted :-)

Comment: you mixed several problems into your code. the main thing: with `gs.evaluate` you are parsing a new groovy script and absolutely not connected with previously parsed scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things worth explaining to understand what is happening here. There are two different scopes in the script you have provided.

The variable `a` gets stored in `GroovyShell` binding object and that is why it is available in every `gs.evaluate()` call. Take a look at this example:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.lang.Script;

final class ExecuteGroovyScriptExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String script = "a = 1.0 \n" +
                "def mul2(x) { 2.0 * x }\n";

        final Binding binding = new Binding();

        final GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(binding);
        final Script sc = gs.parse(script);
        sc.run();

        System.out.printf("binding.getVariable(\"a\") == %s\n", binding.getVariable("a"));
    }
}
```

Running this example produces following output:

```
binding.getVariable("a") == 1.0
```

The second thing is that every `gs.evaluate()` call generates a new `groovy.lang.Script` class which has a completely different context. This is why calling:

```
gs.evaluate("mul2(a)")
```

throws something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script2.mul2() is applicable for argument types: (BigDecimal) values: [1.0]
```

because the script class that gets generated from `gs.evaluate("mul2(a)")` invocation does not contain `mul2(x)` method. The class that gets generated by this call looks something like this:

```
class Script2 extends groovy.lang.Script {
    void run() {
        mul2(a)
    }
}
```

However, the script class returned from `gs.parse(script)` contains `mul2(x)` method, so you can invoke it, but not as `gs.evaluate()` call, but `Script.invokeMethod(name, args)` instead. Something like this:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.lang.Script;

final class ExecuteGroovyScriptExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String script = "a = 1.0 \n" +
                "def mul2(x) { 2.0 * x }\n";

        final GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell();
        final Script sc = gs.parse(script);
        sc.run();

        System.out.printf("mul2(a) = %s%n", sc.invokeMethod("mul2", gs.evaluate("a")));
    }
}
```

This example produces following output:

```
mul2(a) = 2.00
```

Take a look how `mul2(x)` method got invoked. Firstly, we store script returned by `gs.parse(script)` in `sc` variable and it allows us to invoke method defined in this script by following call:

```java
sc.invokeMethod("mul2", gs.evaluate("a"));
```

In this example we take value of `a` variable simply by `gs.evaluate("a")`, but you can also use `binding` object from the first example as well. And keep in mind that if `a` variable was defined like:

```groovy
def a = 1.0
```

or

```groovy
@groovy.transform.Field
def a = 1.0
```

it would not get stored in the `binding` object anymore and in the first case it defines script's local variable `a` and in the second case it defines script class field `a`.

---

Alternatively, if you want to execute following invocation:

```
gs.evaluate("mul2(a)")
```

or even

```
gs.evaluate("Math.sin( a * mul2(Math.PI))")
```

you would have to modify input Groovy script file and replace function `mul2(x)` definition with a closure in the same scope as the `a` variable, so it gets stored in the `binding` object:

```
a = 1.0
mul2 = { x -> 2.0 * x }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but as I explain at the last line of my post, I can do that. I want to use function defined in my groovy file in an expression. Perhaps I have to extend the first script class and evaluate my expression in it. But I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Alternatively you can replace `mul2(x)` with a closure like `mul2 = { x -> 2.0 * x }` in the Groovy script file and then following invocation `gs.evaluate("Math.sin( a * mul2(Math.PI))")` will be evaluated correctly.

Comment: I have edited the initial post, I want to evaluate complex expression as if this expression is at the end of groovy file. And it seems be possible if I use first groovy file to create Script (may be abstract) and extend it in a new script that evaluate the complex expression. I have succeeded if Script is in java, I work to have script in Groovy...

Answer (score 0):

let you have `/my/groovy/classes/Test.groovy`:

```
static mul2( x ) { 2.0 * x }
def    mul3( x ) { 3.0 * x }
```

then you can use class loader to load it as a class and use this class in expressions:

```
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell();
gs.getClassLoader().addClasspath("/my/groovy/classes");

System.out.println( gs.evaluate( "import static Test.*; mul2(5)" ) );
System.out.println( gs.evaluate( "new Test().mul3(6)" ) );
```